# dynamic navigation using mysql php and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have created navigation using mysql php. now i am trying to pass value to another page using ajax.please help me

```
   <ul id="all_navs">

  <?php $sql = mysql_query("select * from sub_category_master where main_category =1");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
   {?>

   <li id="s1">

   <a href="#tab_deals" onclick="showUsers('<?php echo $row['sub_category_id']; ?>')"  id="insert">
   <?php echo $row['sub_category_name']; ?></a>




   </li>

   <?php }?> 


   </ul>
```

Comment: Is it just me or do you not have a hyperlink? All I see is an link to an ID on the same page telling it to call showUsers(value).

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your problem why not try something like this:

```
      <ul id="all_navs">
      <?php $sql = mysql_query("select * from sub_category_master where main_category =1");
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
      echo '<li id="s1">';
      echo '<a href="#tab_deals" onclick="showUsers('.$row['sub_category_id'].')"  id="insert">';
      echo $row['sub_category_name'].'</a>';
      echo '</li>';
      }
      ?> 
      </ul>
```

it would help more if you told us what the problem was.